# jQuery append on .each

Tags: jquery, append, each

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];
jQuery.each( positions, function(players) {
var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');
playerNotesContent.setAttribute('id', 'player_stats_block'+this);
$("#player_stats_block" + this).append (columns); 
})
```

I would like to know, why the `.append` command doesn't work with the `+this`, but while creating div it works. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for my bad English and thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATED**!

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18" ];

jQuery.each( positions, function(players, value) {

var player_id = $("#ctl" + value).attr("href").match(RegExp('players/([^/]+)/details.php$'))[1];
var playerlink = document.getElementById("ctl" + value);

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://www.test.com/players/item/' + player_id,
onload: function(responseDetails) 
{
            var page = jQuery(responseDetails.responseText);
            var columns = jQuery('div.columns',page);
            var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');
            playerNotesContent.setAttribute('id', 'player_stats_block'+value);
            playerlink.parentNode.insertBefore( playerNotesContent, playerlink.nextSibling  );
            $('#player_stats_block00').append (columns); 
}
});
});
```

Like this all values gets appended in #player_stats_block00! I tried several of your answers but i cant get them appended to their correct #player_stats_blockXX. Sorry again for my bad english and thank you all for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to put with *this* ? if this is index or value of the array, you should use the ones provided by the callback function :
    $.each(positions, function(index,value) {

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk: `this` will be a `String` with `"00"` in the first case, `"01"` in the second case, etc.: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is creating a div and setting its `id`, and then trying to *look up* that `div` by that ID. The lookup will fail, because the `div` hasn't been added to the DOM anywhere yet.

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];

jQuery.each( positions, function(players) {
    // Here you're creating the div
    var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');

    // ...and setting its `id` (btw, you can just do playerNotesContent.id = value;)
    playerNotesContent.setAttribute('id', 'player_stats_block'+this);

    // ...and here trying to look it up
    $("#player_stats_block" + this).append (columns); 
});
```

If you're trying to append the div to `columns`, you probably want this instead of your last line:

```
columns.append(playerNotesContent);
```

(Note that [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) adds content to the container you call it on.)

That assumes `columns` is a jQuery object. Otherwise:

```
$(playerNotesContent).appendTo(columns);
```

or

```
$(columns).append(playerNotesContent);
```

(Note that [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) adds the content you call it on to the argument you give it; it's the converse of `append`.)

It's also worth noting that the divs being created have no content, so unless you're styling them, they won't have any dimensions and will be kinda hard to find on the page. :-)

Here's an example assuming `columns` is a jQuery object, and giving the divs some content so you can see them: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/unucaj) | [source](http://jsbin.com/unucaj/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="columns"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var columns = $("#columns");
  var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];

  jQuery.each( positions, function(players) {
    var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');
    playerNotesContent.innerHTML = "Player Stats";
    playerNotesContent.id = 'player_stats_block'+this;
    columns.append(playerNotesContent);
  });  

});
```

Comment: as i see the player_stats_block00, player_stats_block01, player_stats_block02... are successfully created but append dont work!

Comment: @Alex What is `columns`? And where is it defined?

Comment: while `$('#player_stats_block').append (columns);` works ok, `var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');
playerNotesContent.setAttribute('id', 'player_stats_block');playerNotesContent.append(columns);` doesnt.

Comment: @Alex: I've added a live example. Note that your `div` elements are empty, so unless you're styling them, they're going to be hard to find on the page (as they'll have zero height).

Comment: `var page = jQuery(responseDetails.responseText);
var columns = jQuery('div.columns',page);` This is `columns`

Comment: @Alex: Then `columns` is a jQuery object and so `columns.append(playerNotesContent)` should work, assuming your goal is to append these divs to that div. See the live example I gave, and again, note that if the divs have no content, they'll have no height, and you won't see them (unless you have styling being applied to them).

Comment: @Alex: Also, I assume at some point you add `page` to the DOM?

Comment: Its weird but when i use `columns.append(playerNotesContent)` every player_stats_block which got content to append isnt created and the empty ones are successfully created:S

Comment: LOL columns.appendTo(playerNotesContent); WORKED and noone mention it! Thank you all and i think that TJ Crowder deservers my correct answer!

Comment: @Alex: That doesn't make any sense. On the first iteration, that will append `columns` to the `playerNotesContent` div with the ...00 ID, which you're still not putting anywhere in the DOM. And then on the second iteration, it'll **move** it from that one to the one with the ...01 ID.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things I would change. The callback provides the value as the second argument, not the first. Your call to `append` is followed by a space - which breaks. I'm not sure if you want to add `columns` to your new `div`, or the other way around.

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];

$.each( positions, function( index, value ) {
  $( "<div>", { id : 'player_stats_block' + value } )
    .appendTo( "#columns" );
});
```

If `columns` is a legitimate reference to a dom element to begin with, you can put that back into the call to `$.appendTo()` at the end of the primary line. It was unclear as to what this variable represented in your original post.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That value is processed. See http://jsbin.com/uqihaq/edit#javascript,html It appears that if you write out the full tag, the `id` value is not carried over. Including only the opening tag, as I did above, works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm speaking with Scott Gonzalez right now and he tells me the HTML string cannot have any attributes or content. It should be *only* the element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I tested `html` immediately and found that it didn't get carried over either. Scott suggests the possibility of re-writing to look to `<(\w+)` instead, and inferring the nodeName from the HTML string. That would be cool. As of now, it essentially does `document.createElement(selector)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He was already looking at the ticket when I sent it to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];

jQuery.each( positions, function(index, value) {
   $('<div id="player_stats_block'+ value +'"></div>').append(columns);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this with $(this) -->

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05" ];
jQuery.each( positions, function(players) {
var playerNotesContent = document.createElement('div');
playerNotesContent.setAttribute('id', 'player_stats_block'+$(this));
$("#player_stats_block" + $(this)).append (columns); 
})
```

Comment: In this case, `this` will be a `String` object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each It makes no sense whatsoever to call `$()` on them (and will, in fact, result in an error as `$("00")` -- the value on the first iteration -- is an invalid selector).